# Can headphones produce undesirable ultrasounds that can damage my hearing?

Tags: hearing

When I am in bed I have the sensation of hearing a beeping sound, I think it happens after using my Chinese trademark headphones. I have never used them with high volume, because of that I wonder if it could be due to ultrasounds produced by the device.

Comment: Most headphones are incapable of covering the full range of human hearing, much less produce sounds outside that range.

Comment: @Mark high frequencies tend to be easy for headphones.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency response of a headphone is one of the biggest selling points with a wider and flatter response being "better". Ultrasound is typically defined as sounds above 20 kHz. The high end [Sennheiser HD 800 S](http://en-us.sennheiser.com/high-resolution-headphones-3d-audio-hd-800-s) headphones have a flat frequency response out to 51 kHz. Even more reasonably priced headphones can still produce ultra sound (e.g., the [Sennheiser HD 25](http://en-us.sennheiser.com/on-ear-dj-headphone-hd25) can produce frequencies up to 22 kHz).

Comment: Great answer, can you contribute any knowledge on research into effects of >20kHz audio on hearing?